# addHighlightedField() method does not work for termsQuery in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index named `blog`  in ES server.Its type is `article`.Every document belongs to `blog/article` has three field:`title`、`abstract`and`content`.For example:

```
{
  "_index": "blog",
  "_type": "article",
  "_id": "2",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
     "id": 2,
     "title": "Install Git on Windows",
     "abstract": " Git Installation guide",
     "content": "Git is easy to learn and has a tiny ... "
  }
}
```

I build a termsQuery to search documets including `git`:

```
QueryBuilder termquery1 = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("_all", "git");
SearchResponse response1 =client.prepareSearch().setQuery(termquery1)
                          .addHighlightedField("title")
                          .execute().actionGet();
SearchHits hits = response1.getHits();
for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
        HighlightField hField=hit.getHighlightFields().get("title");
        System.out.println(hit.getSource() + "\t" + hit.getHighlightFields());
       System.out.println(hField);
}
```

`System.out.println(hField)` print `null`, My goal is to make key word `git` highlight in all the fields.how to achieve that?

Comment: Can you define "does not work"? It doesn't compile or it compiles but does nothing at runtime? What version of ES are you running?

Comment: I mean ES return documents including key word  `git`，but hit.getHighlightFields() is nothing.I am running ES 2.3.3。

Comment: By "print nothing" do you mean it prints null, or is it printing a memory location?

Comment: There are two documets including`git`,When  executing `for (SearchHit hit : hits) {System.out.println(hit.getHighlightFields());}`,it print `{}{}`.Does it work on your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read elasticsearch reference [Elasticsearch Reference [2.3] » Mapping » Meta-Fields » _all field#highlighting-all-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#highlighting-all-field) and found the reason.

> **Highlighting and the _all field**
>
> A field can only be used for highlighting if the original string value
> is available, either from the _source field or as a stored field.
>
> The _all field is not present in the _source field and it is not
> stored by default, and so cannot be highlighted. There are two
> options. Either store the _all field or highlight the original fields.
>
> **Store the _all fieldedit**
>
> If store is set to true, then the original
> field value is retrievable and can be highlighted.

I change my mapping to set `_all` be stored.

```
{
 "blog": {
     "mappings": {
         "article": {
             "_all": {
                 "store": true,
                "analyzer": "ik_max_word"
             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Then I change termsQuery to queryStringQuery：

```
QueryBuilder strQuery = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("git");
```

then change search method：

```
SearchResponse response1 = client.prepareSearch()
                                 .addHighlightedField("_all")
                                 .setHighlighterPreTags("<span color=\"red\">")
                                 .setHighlighterPostTags("</span>")
                                 .setQuery(strQuery).execute().actionGet();

for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
                    HighlightField hField=hit.getHighlightFields().get("_all");
                    System.out.println("score:"+hit.getScore()+"id:"+hit.getId()
                                       +"\n"+hit.getSourceAsString());
                    System.out.println(hField);
                }
```